# How can I overwrite the save button to change on a custom page?

Tags: mobile, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

When I use the standard save action in the commandButton it goes every time to the default page.

But I want to chamge to a custom page when i click on the save button..how??

I tried a lot of things like this...

```
public Pagereference goHome(){

Pagereference to = Apexpages.currentPage();
     to.setRedirect(true);
return to;
}
```

or

```
public Pagereference goHome(){

Pagereference to = new Pagereference('/apex/mypage?user=guest');    return to;
}


<apex:commandButton value="Save"  action="{!goHome}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple! Check how this example works for you (you'll need to associate the page to a valid Opportunity by adding `?id=006...` in the URL).

```
public class redirectTestCtrl{
    public Opportunity o {get;set;}

    public redirectTestCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl){
        o = (Opportunity)ctrl.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        upsert o;
        //return new PageReference('/home/home.jsp'); // go to home page
        return new PageReference('/' + o.AccountId);  // or to the related Account's page
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="redirectTestCtrl">
    <apex:outputField value="{!o.AccountId}" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!o.Name}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
    </apex:form>
    <span style="visibility:hidden">{!Opportunity.Name} {!Opportunity.AccountId}</span>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: No it's not working in my context. I tried your code in an empty visualforce page.There it's running. I copied it in my visualforce page and there it's not working. The page changed to the url https://XX.XX.visual.force.com/apex/mobilepage?user =DA_HE#/apex/mobilepage. #/apex/mobilepage seeams to be a default page. On my page is using Jquery Mobile too.

Comment: I think you have to be more specific. Have you used both my page and controller? Are you getting any errors? Does it stay on your edit page? Redirect back to the record's "detail view" page like normal save method? Can you try turning on debug logs and examine the output? I've never used jQuery Mobile but I doubt it can swallow page redirects... Can you maybe turn firebug on or any other network sniffer to check the requests?

Answer (score 0):

The standard `save()` method may be called from an extension using `ApexPages.StandardController`. Here's a simple example of how it could be achieved:

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountExtension">
    <apex:form >

        <apex:pageMessages />

        <apex:pageBlock title="Account">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Details">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Extension Class:

```
public class AccountExtension {

    ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    public AccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        stdController = controller;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        stdController.save(); // calling standard save() method
        return null; // return 'null' to stay on same page
    }
}
```